# Transparent background of ViewPagerIndicator library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to have the circles on my background.
I see it just like that:
[image]

My ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Would like to know the solution for that if there is...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Relative layout and out `CirclePageIndicator` on top of `ViewPager`. Otherwise you will see the application's background

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about your question please replace your code by below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent
        />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```